# JQuery Custom Image From Checkbox to Radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to make a custom checkbox with my own images and it works but it's using a Checkbox and I need to use Radio buttons.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#moreinfo").change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "checkbox_unchecked.gif");
   } else {
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "checkbox_checked.gif");
   }
});

 });

</script>
```

Next...here's the HTML:

```
<label for="moreinfo">
     <img src="checkbox_unchecked.gif"/>
     <input name="moreinfo" type="checkbox" id="moreinfo" style="display:none">
</label>
```

If it a question of changing from checkbox to radio type or does the jquery need changing too?

How do I go about this?

Comment: You didn't add the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"` (and add some more radio buttons for testing, grouping them via the `name` attribute, they may not have the same `id` as IDs are unique!). Then, you also need to handle the click event of the replacement images.
But actually, that's going beyond your original question, which you could have solved by simply trying it out. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A Radio Button uses also the attribute checked. So you can switch the element without changing the script (perhaps the gifs).
But your script will never run, because your checkbox/radio button is not displayed.
So you need some functionality to change the status when clicking the image.